# C programming, only the first if statement works

Tags: c, if-statement

I was wondering if anyone could help me understand why only my first if statements is working. Basically, I am working on a l33t speak convertor (lol) and only my first if statement works, here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

void translate (char blurp[]);

int main(void) {

  char message[1024];

  printf("enter a message: \n");
  fgets(message, 1024, stdin);
  translate(message);

return 0;
}



void translate (char blurp[]) {
  int i;
  int length;

  length = strlen(blurp);

  printf("\nHere it is translated: \n");
  for ( i = 0; i != length; i++) {

    if (blurp[i] == 'a') {
      blurp[i] = '4';
      printf("%c", blurp[i]);
    }

    else if (blurp[i] == 'b') {
       blurp[i] = '8';
       printf("%c", blurp[i]);
    }

    else if (blurp[i] == 'e') {
       blurp[i] = '3';
       printf("%c", blurp[i]);

    }

    else if (blurp[i] == 'i') {
       blurp[i] = '|';
       printf("%c", blurp[i]);
    }

   else if (blurp[i] == 'o') {
       blurp[i] = '0';
       printf("%c", blurp[i]);
    }

   else if (blurp[i] == 's') {
       blurp[i] = '5';
       printf("%c", blurp[i]);

    }

    else {
        printf("%c", blurp[i]);
    }


  }

}
```

Comment: Are you saying it only converts the letter 'a', or it only converts the first letter?

Comment: Can't see anything wrong with your code. What exactly is it not doing?

Comment: I compiled it and it seems to work as expected.  What up?

Comment: Basically if i write apple it becomes 4pple but the e doesnt become 3 as it should, with any words I try only the a characters get converted, none of the else if statements seem to be working. Also @Myst how would I do that?

Comment: It works! I don't see any issue with the code above.

Comment: for clarity in the code, strongly suggest using a `switch()` statement rather than all those `if... else if...` statements   Then the char is only evaluated once

Comment: the output stream `stdout` is buffered,  To get the proper output, in a timely manner, in the function: `translate()`, after the `for()` loop, there should be the statement: `printf( "\n");`

Comment: the returned type from a call to `strlen()` is` unsigned long int`, not `int`. So the variable `length` should be declared as a `unsigned long int`.  Since the variable `i` is being compared to `length`, it should also be declared as `unsigned long int`.

Comment: @Myst, the function: `fgets()` always stops inputting characters in time to allow for a trailing NUL byte to be inserted, so the correct second parameter to `fgets()` is `sizeof(message)`

Comment: the variable `length` and the call to `strlen()` can be eliminated by changing: `for ( i = 0; i != length; i++) {` to `i = 0; while( blurb[i] ) { .... i++' }`

Comment: @user3629249 - I stand corrected and I'm removing my comments. Thanks.

Comment: Wow thank you so much!